# Is "Here's wishing xxxx" proper?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I have seen the phrase "Here's wishing you a very happy birthday" in greeting cards.

What is the meaning of "Here's"? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED tells us that, in formulas used in drinking healths, *here’s* is elliptical for *here's a health to*, typically in *Here’s to X*. Analogous expressions do not always allow such an interpretation: the OED’s citations include *Here's luck, Here's how* and *Here's hoping*. However, it is perhaps unsurprising that the usage should be transferred in this way, given the benevolent intent common to all, including the greeting in your example.

One of the best-known uses of the formula is Rick’s in ‘Casablanca’, *Here’s looking at you, kid*, but he was not the first to say it. Earlier instances are found in Lowry and Hemingway.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the expression **here's to** is used as a toast to the health, success etc of someone or something, a salutation and I suppose than also in this case is used as wish but fr a birthday.